# Azure cache Invalid identifier

Tags: caching, azure

So I got this error locally when trying out caching in my worker role:

```
ErrorCode<ERRCA0042>:SubStatus<ES0001>:Invalid identifier: 'Fildela Worker'. Check cache rolename/endpoint in configuration.
```

on the line:

```
<autoDiscover isEnabled="true" identifier="Fildela Worker" />
```

In my MVC app, webconfig.

So I updated both my Azure SDK version to **2.5.1**, and my Visual Studio 2013 version to **Update 4** and voilà! It worked!

**HOWEVER**, when I publish my project as a cloudapp to Azure the error message appear once again. My cache works on localhost but not when published to Azure.

**Why is that?**

Thanks!

**EDIT 1**

I'm using the newest Windows Azure Cache, 2.5.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downgraded my Windows Azure Cache from 2.5.10 to  2.0.0 and it worked! Caching works both on local and when published.

I did however encounter some problems when doing so.

When I installed 2.0.0 I got an exception in the Package Manager Console:

```
Exception calling "Item" with "1" argument(s): "InvalidParameter
Parameter name: index"
```

When I then started my web role I got another exception:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
```

I then checked my ServiceRuntime version and it was 2.3.0.0, not 2.0.0.0.

So I opened my webconfig and added this code:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.3.0.0" newVersion="2.3.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Tada! Done and done!

Answer (score 0):

This particular error is thrown when the Identifier is being validated as a URI for managed cache. Azure cache client tries to first use the given identifier as a role, and if it fails then as an endpoint. So I think your client may be failing to connect to you cache server role. One of the reasons may be that the versions of Azure SDK and cache client are not compatible, but since you are using that may not be the case. Couple of things you can try is cleaning up the client libraries and adding them back to verify client bits are updated. Also you can check/share the client side traces to figure out why the connection to cache server role failed.